# How to decide when to rerender in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, axios

I'm creating a small project with the mern stack. In the homepage of this project, you can see the things that the current user has. THe problem is that the list can change in every moment, because other user can happend to that list other stuff. SO, to make it refresh, I put it in the useEffect hook. The problem now is that my server is reciving a tons of request, and always the same one. I don't know if is the case to set a timer that rerender after x second, to make the work of my server lighter, or there is a way to remake the request to the server in some case. Here is the small code that manage the request:

```
    const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5050/file/getfilesbycreator",{creator:localStorage.getItem('user')})
        .then(res => {
            setFile(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
```

If someone has any suggestion, please tell me. I read something about rerender react, but I didn't found out better way then a timer, or something similar.Thanks

Comment: You should look at websocket/socket.io, it will suit your problem better. Then you can just "listen" for update on your frontend instead of calling your api at every render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the second parameter of your useEffect, you have to indicate which variable you are looking for to rerender.
If you want the useEffect to render only one time, you have to put [] as second parameter like that :

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5050/file/getfilesbycreator",{creator:localStorage.getItem('user')})
    .then(res => {
        setFile(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [])
```

If you have a variable that can change, for example 'file', just add it in the array :

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5050/file/getfilesbycreator",{creator:localStorage.getItem('user')})
    .then(res => {
        setFile(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [file])
```